# onPause() how to determine if a new app activity is being called or if the app is being paused entirely?

Tags: android

In onPause how do I determine if a new app activity is being called or if the app is being paused entirely ? This would be useful for animating to an options screen (with a push left animation) or animating to homescreen (with a zoom out animation).

When the user presses the home screen I only get notified by this event in onPause so that I can override the animation to the home screen. But if I do this, I also override the animation to other screens and in some cases I want to customize this.

Comment: As you can know when you are launching your activities, you can use a flag or any other approach to set that you have called startActivity() and check that in the onPause(). It´s not a fancy solution, but it involves only a couple of lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement onkeydown and check for KEYCODE_HOME. That way you will be notified when user going to home screen.

Answer (score 2):

Following method of `Activity` will be called when user presses `Home` button.
You can place code what you want to do.

```
@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
    super.onUserLeaveHint();
    Log.d("TAG","Home Button Pressed");
    //some code here..
}
```

Comment: Tried this and it also gets called for other activities from my app :| (or at least this is the case with the X86 emulator)